# Cocos2d and UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone

I am developing an IPhone cocos2d app with a scene like the the one depicted in the following image (I hope you can see that): 
[image]

On the right there is a vertically scrollable menu contained in a separated layer (menulayer) which is itself contained in the main scene's layer. On the left there is a back button contained in the main scene's layer. 
I am trying to exploit the UIScrollView as described in [this link](http://www.xcombinator.com/2010/09/08/a-paging-uiscrollview-in-cocos2d-with-previews/comment-page-1/#comment-35850). However, despite I can see the UIScrollView working I am experimenting some problems:

1) while the menulayer actually scrolls it seems the menu does not. In fact when a press the menu item 8 the menu item 4 is selected, when I press the menu item 7 the menu item 3 is selected and so on.

2) the back button only works when the menulayer is at its first position

Do you have any idea of how shall I do to fix it?

Comment: is it still possible to put a bounty on questions? I would like to put a bounty on this question but I can not see how

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check you selectors. calls selectors from proper controls. check it carefully.Your problem shows your menu item 8 th selector bind with 4th same for others. some mis binding of selectors is present in your code so check them properly.

Comment: that is not correct. Selectors are correctly set. Other ideas?