# COCOS2D: ScrollView inside a CCScene blocks animation

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, cocos2d-iphone

I have a CCScene. In its right side I need to have a UIScrollView with some menu elements. I did it this way as I have explained in this previous question [Cocos2d and UIScrollView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6489182/cocos2d-and-uiscrollview)

here is the method creating my scene

```
  +(id) scene: (int) wld{
    CCScene *scene = [CCScene node];
    LevelsMenu *layer = [LevelsMenu node];
    layer = [layer init:wld];
    [scene addChild: layer];
    [layer setScrollView:[LevelMenuControlView alloc]];
    [[[CCDirector sharedDirector] openGLView] addSubview:layer.scrollView.view];
    return scene;
 }
```

notice that LevelMenuControlView is just an UIViewController implemented this way:

```
 - (void)loadView{
 LevelMenuView *scrollView = [[LevelMenuView alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen 
    mainScreen].applicationFrame];

scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(862, 480);

scrollView.delegate = scrollView;
[scrollView setUserInteractionEnabled:TRUE];
[scrollView setScrollEnabled:TRUE];
[scrollView setShowsVerticalScrollIndicator:FALSE];
[scrollView setShowsHorizontalScrollIndicator:FALSE];
self.view = scrollView;

[scrollView release];
 }
```

While LevelMenuView is the UIScrollView containing the menu elements

It works quite fine. Now the problem is that in the left side of the scene I have a sprite animation that, If I do not touch the screen fine but as soon as I drag  the scroll view up or down stops or goes at the same speed of my scrolling finger!!!

Any idea?

Comment: What's the code that animates the Sprite? Maybe it also reacts to touch events? And do you mean by animate that the sprite moves (changes position) or that the sprite's frame change (image animation)?

Comment: I just load a spritesheet in the CCSpriteFrameCache and schedule a selector in which I periodically change the sprite displayed frame with a sprite taken from the FrameCache

Comment: So then maybe you're experiencing a simple performance problem, could that be it?

Comment: It looks like it but I guess it is not as if a keep my finger in a point without moving it the animation stops as well. It starts moving again as soon as I move the touch (and at the same speed). It is very strange and I can not figure out where the problem could be. I have also tried to spawn the sprite update in a different thread but I have experimented the same behaviour

Comment: Are you maybe calling pause/resume or startAnimation/stopAnimation on CCDirector whenever the UIScrollView has the focus?

Comment: No unfortunately it is not that simple :(

Comment: I have just answered my question with a link of some guys having addressed this issue. It seems there is always something to learn :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found this link where someone already experienced the same problem and posted a solution which actually works

http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/11645

It basically consists in adding this code to the scroll view:

```
// This should go in your interface.
 NSTimer *timer;

// Override
- (void)setContentOffset:(CGPoint)contentOffset {
// UIScrollView uses UITrackingRunLoopMode.
// NSLog([[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] currentMode]);

// If we're dragging, mainLoop is going to freeze.
if (self.dragging && !self.decelerating) {

// Make sure we haven't already created our timer.
if (timer == nil) {

 // Schedule a new UITrackingRunLoopModes timer, to fill in for    
 CCDirector while we drag.
        timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:[[CCDirector sharedDirector] animationInterval] target:self selector:@selector(animateWhileDragging) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

                    // This could also be NSRunLoopCommonModes
        [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer:timer forMode:UITrackingRunLoopModes];
    }
}

// If we're decelerating, mainLoop is going to stutter.
if (self.decelerating && !self.dragging) {

    // Make sure we haven't already created our timer.
    if (timer == nil) {

        // Schedule a new UITrackingRunLoopMode timer, to fill in for CCDirector while we decellerate.
        timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:[[CCDirector sharedDirector] animationInterval] target:self selector:@selector(animateWhileDecellerating) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
        [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer:timer forMode:UITrackingRunLoopMode];
    }
}

[super setContentOffset:contentOffset];
}
- (void)animateWhileDragging {

// Draw.
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] drawScene];

if (!self.dragging) {

    // Don't need this timer anymore.
    [timer invalidate];
    timer = nil;
}
}
- (void)animateWhileDecellerating {

// Draw.
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] drawScene];

if (!self.decelerating) {

    // Don't need this timer anymore.
    [timer invalidate];
    timer = nil;
}
}
```

Thanks a lot to these guys